# Finding Similarity between 2 sentences using word2vec of sentence with python

Tags: python, nlp

I want to calculate the similarity between two sentences using word2vectors, I am trying to get the vectors of a sentence so that i can calculate the average of a sentence vectors to find the cosine similarity. i have tried this code but its not working. the output it gives the sentence-vectors with ones. i want the actual vectors of sentences in sentence_1_avg_vector & sentence_2_avg_vector.

Code:

```
    #DataSet#
    sent1=[['What', 'step', 'step', 'guide', 'invest', 'share', 'market', 'india'],['What', 'story', 'Kohinoor', 'KohiNoor', 'Diamond']]
    sent2=[['What', 'step', 'step', 'guide', 'invest', 'share', 'market'],['What', 'would', 'happen', 'Indian', 'government', 'stole', 'Kohinoor', 'KohiNoor', 'diamond', 'back']]
    sentences=sent1+sent2

    #''''Applying Word2vec''''#
    word2vec_model=gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, size=100, min_count=5)
    bin_file="vecmodel.csv"
    word2vec_model.wv.save_word2vec_format(bin_file,binary=False)

    #''''Making Sentence Vectors''''#
    def avg_feature_vector(words, model, num_features, index2word_set):
        #function to average all words vectors in a given paragraph
        featureVec = np.ones((num_features,), dtype="float32")
        #print(featureVec)
        nwords = 0
        #list containing names of words in the vocabulary
        index2word_set = set(model.wv.index2word)# this is moved as input param for performance reasons
        for word in words:
            if word in index2word_set:
                nwords = nwords+1
                featureVec = np.add(featureVec, model[word])
                print(featureVec)
        if(nwords>0):
            featureVec = np.divide(featureVec, nwords)
        return featureVec

    i=0
    while i<len(sent1):
        sentence_1_avg_vector = avg_feature_vector(mylist1, model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word))
        print(sentence_1_avg_vector)

        sentence_2_avg_vector = avg_feature_vector(mylist2, model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word))
        print(sentence_2_avg_vector)

        sen1_sen2_similarity =  1 - spatial.distance.cosine(sentence_1_avg_vector,sentence_2_avg_vector)
        print(sen1_sen2_similarity)

        i+=1
```

the output this code gives:

```
[ 1.  1.  ....  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  ....  1.  1.]
0.999999898245
[ 1.  1.  ....  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  ....  1.  1.]
0.999999898245
```

Comment: Do you want to compute vector representations for your sentences by looking up and averaging pre-computed word2vec-vectors or do you want to compute them from scratch? Your code looks like you're trying the latter... But I don't think you can learn any useful embeddings from just two sentences. People usually use millions of words for that.

Comment: Maybe this would help.

Comment: these are not actually two sentences.. my data set contain 8 lacs+ rows of sentences.. for convenience i have mentioned here some sample data to convey my concept...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you please tell me what's mylist1, and mylist2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is the following:

1. Obtain vector representations from word2vec for every word in your sentence.
2. Average all word vectors of a sentence to obtain a sentence representation.
3. Compute cosine similarity between the vectors of two sentences.

While the code for 2 and 3 looks fine to me in general (haven't tested it though), the issue is probably in step 1. What you are doing in your code with

`word2vec_model=gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, size=100, min_count=5)`

is to initialize a new word2vec model. If you would then call `word2vec_model.train()`, gensim would train a new model on your sentences so you can use the resulting vectors for each word afterwards. But, in order to obtain useful word vectors that capture things like similarity, you usually need to train the word2vec model on a lot of data - the [model provided by Google](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) was trained on 100 billion words.

What you probably want to do instead is to use a pretrained word2vec model and use it with gensim in your code. According to the [documentation of gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), this can be done with the `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format` method.

Comment: i exactly have problem in step one.. the problem might be with the vocabulary.. when i save the vector model in bin file it give me the vectors of just letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd section (converting text into feature vectors) is wrong. 
You have to replace:

`featureVec = np.ones((num_features,), dtype="float32")`

with

`featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float32")`.

If none of the words were found in the dictionary (index2word_set), then it should give them all zeros.
That solved my issue.