# Graph to connect sentences

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, networkx, word2vec

I have a list of sentences of a few topics (two) like the below:

```
Sentences
Trump says that it is useful to win the next presidential election. 
The Prime Minister suggests the name of the winner of the next presidential election.
In yesterday's conference, the Prime Minister said that it is very important to win the next presidential election. 
The Chinese Minister is in London to discuss about climate change.
The president Donald Trump states that he wants to win the presidential election. This will require a strong media engagement.
The president Donald Trump states that he wants to win the presidential election. The UK has proposed collaboration. 
The president Donald Trump states that he wants to win the presidential election. He has the support of his electors.
```

As you can see there is similarity in sentences.

[image]

I am trying to relate multiple sentences and visualise the characteristics of them by using a graph (directed). The graph is built from a similarity matrix, by applying row ordering of sentences as shown above.
I created a new column, Time, to show the order of sentences, so first row (Trump says that....) is at time 1; second row (The Prime Minister suggests...) is at time 2, and so on.
Something like this

```
Time    Sentences
1           Trump said that it is useful to win the next presidential election. 
2           The Prime Minister suggests the name of the winner of the next presidential election.

3           In today's conference, the Prime Minister said that it is very important to win the next presidential election. 

...
```

I would like then to find the relationships in order to have a clear overview of the topic.
Multiple paths for a sentence would show that there are multiple information associated with it.
To determine similarity between two sentences, I tried to extract nouns and verbs as follows:

```
noun=[]
verb=[]
for  index, row in df.iterrows():
      nouns.append([word for word,pos in pos_tag(row[0]) if pos == 'NN'])
      verb.append([word for word,pos in pos_tag(row[0]) if pos == 'VB'])
```

as they are keywords in whatever sentence.
So when a keyword (noun or verb) appears in sentence x but not in the other sentences, it represents a difference between these two sentences.
I think a better approach, however, could be using word2vec or gensim (WMD).

This similarity has to be calculated for each sentence.
I would like to build a graph which shows the content of the sentence in my example above.
Since there are two topics (Trump and Chinese Minister), for each of them I need to look for sub-topics. Trump has sub-topic presidential election, for example. A node in my graph should represent a sentence. Words in each node represent differences for the sentences, showing new info in the sentence. For example, the word `states` in sentence at time 5 is in adjacent sentences at time 6 and 7.
I would like just to find a way to have similar results as shown in picture below. I have tried using mainly nouns and verbs extraction, but probably it is not the right way to proceed.
What I tried to do has been to consider sentence at time 1 and compare it with other sentences, assigning a similarity score (with noun and verbs extraction but also with word2vec), and repeat it for all the other sentences.
But my problem is now on how to extract difference to create a graph that can make sense.

For the part of the graph, I would consider to use networkx (DiGraph):

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
N = Network(directed=True)
```

to show direction of relationships.

I provided a different example to make it be clearer (but if you worked with the previous example, it would be fine as well. Apologies for the inconvenience, but since my first question was not so clear, I had to provide also a better, probably easier, example).

Comment: Just want to tell you that it's not at all clear what you want (at least not to me), so I think that's why you don't get any comments or answers. I suggest you try to mention the functioning code you already have, so people have an example to run, with the sample data embedded in the code (what you mention is not all the code, as, i.e., it doesn't collect nouns). We also need the exact output you would like for that exact input. Currently, it is not very clear what exact output you would like. So if you mention the functioning code and the exact wanted output, it might be easier to help.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I accidentally delete the part for nouns collecting. I just added. My expected output would be something shown in the picture (a network/graph that can show relationships between sentences based on nouns and verbs). For the part of graph I am considering networkx (DiGraph as it is important the sequence). I have not a working code. I can post what I have done but it might appear just a bit confuse and wrong

Comment: please let me know if it is a bit clearer now. I am trying to follow, but without success, this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441510/building-terms-relations-within-a-network . I think this can be considered a semantic net where I am considering the similarity between sentences.

Comment: Hm, it's not clearer to me, but that could just be me! When I work, I start with some specific input and then create the specific wanted output manually first. A bit like test-driven development: I have to know exactly what I want, given specific input, before I can write code that does that. And to me, the graph is not clear. Is the graph complete? And is it exact, given the mentioned input? Is your idea totally clear in your own mind, or are you uncertain what the exact output should be? You say you want "something similar to following", but not "I want exactly this output".

Comment: Sometimes when I cannot solve a problem, the real problem is that what I want to do is not absolutely clear in my mind. So creating the exact wanted output can make it clearer, as it forces me to be exact. I'm unsure if this is also the case here, or if it's just me who is too dumb to understand. 

Comment: no problem Jesper. I will try to re-word it providing a better example in a few minutes. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't implement NLP for verb / noun separation, just added a list of good words.
They can be extracted and normalized with [spacy](https://spacy.io/) relatively easy.
Please note that `walk` occurs in 1,2,5 sentences and forms a triad.

```py
import re
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("ggplot")

sentences = [
    "I went out for a walk or walking.",
    "When I was walking, I saw a cat. ",
    "The cat was injured. ",
    "My mum's name is Marylin.",
    "While I was walking, I met John. ",
    "Nothing has happened.",
]

G = nx.Graph()
# set of possible good words
good_words = {"went", "walk", "cat", "walking"}

# remove punctuation and keep only good words inside sentences
words = list(
    map(
        lambda x: set(re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", x).lower().split()).intersection(
            good_words
        ),
        sentences,
    )
)

# convert sentences to dict for furtehr labeling
sentences = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(sentences)}

# add nodes
for i, sentence in sentences.items():
    G.add_node(i)

# add edges if two nodes have the same word inside
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(words)):
        for edge_label in words[i].intersection(words[j]):
            G.add_edge(i, j, r=edge_label)

# compute layout coords
coord = nx.spring_layout(G)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 14))

# set label coords a bit upper the nodes
node_label_coords = {}
for node, coords in coord.items():
    node_label_coords[node] = (coords[0], coords[1] + 0.04)

# draw the network
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=coord)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=coord)
edge_labels = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=coord)
node_labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=node_label_coords, labels=sentences)
plt.title("Sentences network")
plt.axis("off")
```

[image]

**Update**
If you want to measure the similarity between different sentences, you may want to calculate the difference between sentence embedding. 
This gives you an opportunity to find semantic similarity between sentences with different words like "A soccer game with multiple males playing" and "Some men are playing a sport". Almost SoTA approach using BERT can be found [here](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert/), more simple approaches are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869881/finding-similarity-between-2-sentences-using-word2vec-of-sentence-with-python).
Since you have similarity measure, just replace add_edge block to add new edge only if similarity measure is greater than some threshold. Resulting add edges code will look like this:

```
# add edges if two nodes have the same word inside
tresold = 0.90
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(words)):
        # suppose you have some similarity function using BERT or PCA
        similarity = check_similarity(sentences[i], sentences[j])
        if similarity > tresold:
            G.add_edge(i, j, r=similarity)
```

Comment: Thank you ilia. No, it is not my homework ;) I am just asking myself a lot of questions and try to answer. Sometime I just can find by myself a solution, sometimes (as in this case) not. Apologies if I changed the example I first provided, but since it was not completely clear what I was asking for some users, I thought it was better to provide a new one, a bit easier since the topics are limited in number.

Comment: That's ok, I've already modified the header.
I'll borrow this question for my SNA class =)

Comment: If you want to measure the similarity between different sentences, you may want to calculate the difference between sentence embeddings.

Comment: This gives you an opportunity to find semantic similarity between sentences with different words like "A soccer game with multiple males playing" and "Some men are playing a sport". Almost SoTA approach using BERT can be found [here](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert/), more [simple approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869881/finding-similarity-between-2-sentences-using-word2vec-of-sentence-with-python).

Comment: Since you have similarity measure, just replace add_edge block to add new edge only if similarity measure is greater than some threshold.

Comment: Thanks ilia for the useful information and advice. Appreciated. I will have a look at BERT. I think it actually can be a very good approach as this example is related to semantic similarity between sentences, as you also noticed. I have not get your last comment. Could you please explain me better what you mean? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to tokenize, remove the stop words and create the vocabulary. Then draw the graph based on this vocabulary. I am showing below and example on unigram based tokens but much better approach will be to identify phrases (ngrams) and use them as vocabulary instead of unigrams. Sentence similarly will be pictorially depicted by nodes (and the corresponding sentences) having more in and degree.

Sample:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


corpus = [
  "Trump says that it is useful to win the next presidential election",
  "The Prime Minister suggests the name of the winner of the next presidential election",
  "In yesterday conference, the Prime Minister said that it is very important to win the next presidential election",
  "The Chinese Minister is in London to discuss about climate change",
  "The president Donald Trump states that he wants to win the presidential election. This will require a strong media engagement",
  "The president Donald Trump states that he wants to win the presidential election. The UK has proposed collaboration",
  "The president Donald Trump states that he wants to win the presidential election. He has the support of his electors",
]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words="english")
vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

all_edges = []
for s in corpus:
  edges = []
  previous = None
  for w in s.split():
    w = w.lower()
    if w in vectorizer.get_feature_names():
      if previous:
        edges.append((previous, w))
        #print (previous, w)
      previous = w   

  all_edges.append(edges)


plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = 500)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'm', 'c', 'k']
for i, edges in enumerate(all_edges):
  nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=edges, edge_color=colors[i], arrows=True)
#nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=black_edges, arrows=False)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]